# Weighted average using pivot tables in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have written some code to compute a weighted average using pivot tables in pandas. However, I am not sure how to add the actual column which performs the weighted averaging (Add a new column where each row contains value of 'cumulative'/'COUNT').

The data looks like so:

```
VALUE   COUNT   GRID    agb
1       43      1476    1051
2       212     1476    2983
5       7       1477    890
4       1361    1477    2310
```

Here is my code:

```
# Read input data
lup_df  = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(o_dir+LUP+'.csv',index_col=False)
# Insert a new column with area * variable
lup_df['cumulative'] = lup_df['COUNT']*lup_df['agb']

# Create and output pivot table
lup_pvt = pandas.pivot_table(lup_df, 'agb', rows=['GRID'])         
# TODO: Add a new column where each row contains value of 'cumulative'/'COUNT'
lup_pvt.to_csv(o_dir+PIVOT+'.csv',index=True,header=True,sep=',')
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So you want, for each value of `grid`, the weighted average of the `agb` column where the weights are the values in the `count` column.  If that interpretation is correct, I think this does the trick with `groupby`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

n = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({'count': np.random.choice(np.arange(10)+1, n),
                   'grid': np.random.choice(np.arange(10)+50, n),
                   'value': np.random.randn(n) + 12})

df['prod'] = df['count'] * df['value']
grouped = df.groupby('grid').sum()
grouped['wtdavg'] = grouped['prod'] / grouped['count']

print grouped

      count       value        prod     wtdavg
grid                                          
50       22   57.177042  243.814417  11.082474
51       27   58.801386  318.644085  11.801633
52       11   34.202619  135.127942  12.284358
53       24   59.340084  272.836636  11.368193
54       39  137.268317  482.954857  12.383458
55       47   79.468986  531.122652  11.300482
56       17   38.624369  214.188938  12.599349
57       22   38.572429  279.948202  12.724918
58       27   36.492929  327.315518  12.122797
59       34   60.851671  408.306429  12.009013
```

Or, if you want to be a bit slick and write a weighted average function you can use over and over:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

n = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({'count': np.random.choice(np.arange(10)+1, n),
                   'grid': np.random.choice(np.arange(10)+50, n),
                   'value': np.random.randn(n) + 12})

def wavg(val_col_name, wt_col_name):
    def inner(group):
        return (group[val_col_name] * group[wt_col_name]).sum() / group[wt_col_name].sum()
    inner.__name__ = 'wtd_avg'
    return inner

slick = df.groupby('grid').apply(wavg('value', 'count'))

print slick

grid
50      11.082474
51      11.801633
52      12.284358
53      11.368193
54      12.383458
55      11.300482
56      12.599349
57      12.724918
58      12.122797
59      12.009013
dtype: float64
```

Comment: When I print slick, the column header 'wtd_avg' is missing. Is there any way I can get it back? thanks!

Comment: It all depends what you eventually want to do with this column.  Right now `slick` is a `pd.Series` object.  If you want to tack it on to another dataframe, just assign it to a new column there: `other_df['my_nifty_weighted_average'] = slick`.  Or if you want it to be a named `series`, just do `slick.name = 'my_nifty_weighted_average'`

Comment: Realize this is mega old but out of curiousity...what does the inner function do here?